What is the significance of Adam & Son of Man in Ps 8 compared to Man & Son of Adam in Ps 144?
Only 4 times in the Hebrew Masoretic text is the question asked "What is Man?" twice in the Book of Job & twice in the Psalms, Psalms 8 & 144.
In Psalm 8:4 the question is "What is man (enos - Strongs 582), that thou art mindful of him?  And the son of man (Adam - Str 120,) that thou visitest him?" (KJV)
In Psalm 144:3 the question is "LORD, what is man (Adam - Str 120), that thou takest knowledge of him! Or the son of man (enos - Str 582), that thou makest account of him!"
The words 'Adam' (for some 'Adom') & 'man' (enos) are transposed in Ps 144 as compared to Ps 8.   Are there any opinions regarding the significance of the transposition?

Posting the four verses side-by-side might make this clearer.

Psalm 8:4 (1000-600BCE)
מָֽה־אֱנֹ֥ושׁ כִּֽי־תִזְכְּרֶ֑נּוּ וּבֶן־אָ֝דָ֗ם כִּ֣י
תִפְקְדֶֽנּוּ׃
what is man that You are mindful of him, or the son of man that
You care for him?


Psalm 144:3 (500-400BCE)
יְֽהוָ֗ה מָה־אָ֭דָם וַתֵּדָעֵ֑הוּ בֶּן־אֱ֝נֹ֗ושׁ
וַֽתְּחַשְּׁבֵֽהוּ׃
O LORD, what is man, that You regard him, the son of man that You think of him?


Job 7:17 (600-400BCE)
מָֽה־אֱ֭נֹושׁ כִּ֣י תְגַדְּלֶ֑נּוּ וְכִי־תָשִׁ֖ית אֵלָ֣יו
לִבֶּֽךָ׃
What is man, that you make so much of him, and that you set your
heart on him,


Job 15:14 (600-400BCE)
מָֽה־אֱנֹ֥ושׁ כִּֽי־יִזְכֶּ֑ה וְכִֽי־יִ֝צְדַּ֗ק יְל֣וּד אִשָּֽׁה׃
What is man, that he can be pure? Or he who is born of a woman,
that he can be righteous?

It might be that... Psalm 8 was the venerated original; Job lifts the phrase from there; and then Psalm 144 wants to start the line with יְֽהוָ֗ה.
We should only really call this a 'transposition' if we're sure the poet of Psalm 144 is using Psalm 8 or a particular source directly. He might also be using Job. And who knows what else from the spoken corpus/oral tradition.
I'm not an expert in Ancient Hebrew poetry, but מָֽה־אֱנֹ֥ושׁ כִּֽי־תִזְכְּרֶ֑נּוּ in Psalm 8 is the same number of syllables as יְֽהוָ֗ה מָה־אָ֭דָם וַתֵּדָעֵ֑הוּ in Psalm 144, so a likely explanation is going to be that the psalmist thought it scanned better that way round.
Both Psalms open and close with יְֽהוָ֗ה, but Psalm 144 takes this down to the level of making it the second word of the first verse and the penultimate word of the last verse.
Roughly the first half of 144 has its blocks of sense starting with יְֽהוָ֗ה, contrasting with a second half where man is central (with a very chiastic last verse placing the man-God contrast in microcosm). So that might be why they wanted to start verse 3 with יְֽהוָ֗ה - to match with verse 1 and verse 5. and thereby distinguish v1-8 from v9-14, with v15 summing it up.
Psalm 8, being older, is simpler - first half about God, second half about man, last verse repeats first verse.
But I don't think the words in Psalm 144:3 being the other way round signals any sort of thematic contrast or theological significance. The placement of אָ֭דָם is metrical.

I upvoted your answer as well researched and thought provoking. I wish downvoters would explain their objections. I would like to know if they object to your dating (some believe Job to have been written before the psalms) or what. I see no reason to presume borrowing in these cases.  Forms such as those under discussion could have been quite common in the oral tradition before being written down.

@DanFefferman - I fully agree - there is nothing in this answer deserving a downvote.  So, I have also upvoted it.

gentlemen, please don't feel you need to atone for your community. My word-studies are all upvoted, so long as I don't interpret. Which tells your visitors: "you may be able to read the words, but they mean what we say they mean." Which is to be expected on a site that most of all prizes simplicity and adherence-to-format.
